# What is the difference between PHP FPM and PHP FPM Public?

Tags: php, vps, vestacp

I am new to the VPS hosting server configuration. Recently bought a VPS package and configured the hosting server with [MyVest](https://myvestacp.com/).
When I trying to select PHP version from the PHP version list, I am seeing the following options along with other PHP versions:

1. PHP-FPM-73
2. PHP-FPM-73-public
3. PHP-FPM-74
4. PHP-FPM-74-public

Now I want to know, what is the actual difference when choosing between PHP-FPM-73 and PHP-FPM-73-public OR PHP-FPM-74 and PHP-FPM-74-public versions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [myVesta forums](https://forum.myvestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=53):

> PHP-FPM-73-public is template for Laravel projects, difference is just docroot folder, it's /public_html/public/ instead of /public_html/ (which is default).

So you could probably use it for any project that wants the website root to live in a deeper folder than normal, such as Laravel, Symfony and Drupal.